# Recording and Playing audio on react-native-web

Tags: react-native, react-native-web

I'm trying to figure out a way to record and play audio using react-native-web. I have found several ways to successfully do it in android and IOS but can't figure out how to do it on web. I'm also using Expo in my project. Any help is much appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

I noticed that Expo's Audio ( `expo install expo-av`, `import { Audio } from 'expo-av';`) supports web as mentioned in their doc: https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/audio/

edit

for playing audio on MOBILE: (React Native Expo)

```
/**
 * load, play and unload sound
 * @param soundObject e.g new Audio() 
 * @param audio e.g: require('audio.mp3')
 */
export async function playAudio(soundObject, audio) {
    try {
        await soundObject.loadAsync(audio);
        const playRes = await soundObject.playAsync();
        soundObject.setOnPlaybackStatusUpdate(async (status) => {
            if (status.didJustFinish === true) {
                await soundObject.unloadAsync()
            }
        })
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('play audio err:', error);
        await soundObject.unloadAsync()
        soundObject.setOnPlaybackStatusUpdate(null)
    }
}
```

where for example:

```
import { Audio } from 'expo-av';
const soundObject = new Audio.Sound();
```

and to use the function:

```
playAudio(entranceSound, require('audio.mp3'))
```

for RECORDING on WEB we used (ReactJS):

```
recorder.current = new MediaRecorder(stream, { mimeType: 'audio/webm' });
```

and calling the .start() function,

! all on the internet if this seems useful for someone to check out

Comment: it explicitly says support is 'pending'. very frustrating finding this on google